# How to make a route contains url scheme in angular

Tags: angular

In my project I need to make a route that contains ios app opening URL scheme.

http://example.com/app-opener://install-open-app/163Q70xR

what I have tried.

```js
    {
        path: 'app-opener*',
        component: StoreComponent
    }
```

but its not working.

I have also tried matcher function but it redirects me to http://example.com/app-opener:
everything removed after :(colon).

why its not opening store component please help.

Comment: ca you provide more info about your code

Comment: @PiyushJain as in my question you can see I just need to open store component on this url http://example.com/app-opener://install-open-app/163Q70xR

Comment: What about `example.com/app-opener/install-open-app/163Q70xR` ? If it is possible for the client application, it will be easier to code

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle no I need same for ios URL scheme

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer 0** : this solution uses a feature that is not documented on angular.io

**Disclaimer 1** : this is my worst Angular piece of code ever. Don't judge me, you have been warned.

**Disclaimer 2** : the way I do it is not officially supported, particularly for the `://` part in the url. Even if it might work now, it can break in the future.

I **strongly** encourage you to find a better URL scheme with your colleagues. Something like `example.com/app-opener/install-open-app/163Q70xR` will be easier to maintain.

You might also rewrite the URL using `apache/nginx`

That being said, I still wanted to know if it was possible. The answer is...  yes. (But please don't do that)

You can implement custom routing regex using a `UrlMatcher`. As you can see in the code :

**router.d.ts** :

````js
/**
 * A function for matching a route against URLs. Implement a custom URL matcher
 * for `Route.matcher` when a combination of `path` and `pathMatch`
 * is not expressive enough. Cannot be used together with `path` and `pathMatch`.
 *
 * The function takes the following arguments and returns a `UrlMatchResult` object.
 * * *segments* : An array of URL segments.
 * * *group* : A segment group.
 * * *route* : The route to match against.
 *
 * The following example implementation matches HTML files.
 *
 * ```
 * export function htmlFiles(url: UrlSegment[]) {
 *   return url.length === 1 && url[0].path.endsWith('.html') ? ({consumed: url}) : null;
 * }
 *
 * export const routes = [{ matcher: htmlFiles, component: AnyComponent }];
 * ```
 *
 * @publicApi
 */
export declare type UrlMatcher = (segments: UrlSegment[], group: UrlSegmentGroup, route: Route) => UrlMatchResult | null;
````

BUT : the problem with you URL is that `://install-open-app` will confuse the `Router`. Angular will erase everything after this part at the end of the routing. You can still read the app code using `window.location` **during the routing**. Put it in the route data so that you can read it later.

You can implement something like this (tested, works on my machine) :

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    matcher: (url: UrlSegment[], group: UrlSegmentGroup, route: Route) => {
      const code = window.location.pathname.split('install-open-app/')[1];
      route.data = { code };
      return url.length === 1 && url[0].path.startsWith('app-opener') ? ({consumed: url}) : null;
    },
    component: OpenerComponent,
  },
];
```

Then, in the component, you can get the code back from the route data :

```js
export class OpenerComponent implements OnInit {

  code: string;

  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    route.data.subscribe((data) => this.code = data.code);
  }
```

Comment: thanks but it removes everything after :colon

Comment: Oh... the "app code" part seems to be usable only in the UrlMatcher... trying to figure a solution

Comment: @AkashKumarVerma Finally found a way using route data. I edited the answer

Comment: Note : if you want to keep the app code in the URL, you can still use this piece of code in order to make  an intermediate component that will `router.navigate()` the user to a cleaner URL. The best solution is still to have a cleaner URL from the very beginning.

Comment: thank you so much for helping me yes I got the code  but it removes everything after :colon. i think it's not possible in angular

Comment: @AkashKumarVerma the part after :colon is still readable during the navigation. It is removed only at the end of the navigation. Therefore, you can still put it in the data and use it to navigate the user to a URL that includes this code. You could just replace  the code in the constructor of `OpenerComponent` with `router.navigate` and it would do the trick. On my computer, the code is displayed correctly even if it disappeared from the URL